# MaterializeCSS autocomplete edit css

Tags: css, materialize

I have been trying to customize a search bar that I initially created using MaterializeCSS. I am using the Autocomplete functionality in order to make searching easier. However, I have been unable to successfully change the green MaterializeCSS font colors and size, etc. Both in the input and in the dropdown that appears when people search. I would very much appreciate if someone here could help. I have tried changing the CSS in lots of ways but have been unsuccessful.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">

<section id="search" class="section white-text blue section-search center scrollspy">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12">
        <h3>Search destinations</h3>
        <div class="input-field">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">search</i>
          <input type="text" class="white grey-text autocomplete" id="autocomplete-input" placeholder="Search" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
    .section-search input {
      padding: 5px !important;
      font-size: 18px !important;
      width: 90% !important;
      border: #f4f4f4 3px solid !important;
      background-color: red !important;
    }

    .section-search input .autocomplete {
      color: #000 !important;
    }
```

Javascript:

```
  // Autocomplete
  const ac = document.querySelector('.autocomplete');
  M.Autocomplete.init(ac, {
    data: {
      "Banana": null,
      "Apple": null,
      "Coconut": null,
      "Carrot": null,
      "Pear": null,
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your `input` element has a class of `.grey-text` that has a `color: #9e9e9e !important;` declaration which will override any color styles you add.  I'd recommend removing that class (and maybe the `.white` class):

```
<input type="text" class="autocomplete" id="autocomplete-input" placeholder="Search" />
```

And your CSS has an extra space between `input` and `.autocomplete` (also don't need the `!important` anymore):

```
.section-search input.autocomplete {
  color: #000;
}
.input-field .prefix.active {
  color: #000!important;
}
.dropdown-content li>a, .dropdown-content li>span {
  color: #000!important;
}
.autocomplete-content li .highlight {
  color: red!important;
}
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/q9mpasnt/5/)**

Comment: Thank you for you help with this! Do you know how I can also change the font color of the dropdown that initializes on Autocomplete? And the :active for the icon? thanks.

Comment: I don't see the code for the dropdown - do you have a compiled version of that so I can help style it?

Comment: In the HTML I have now included the link to the materialize CSS + Javascript. I believe this is all you need to add in order for the dropdown to appear.

Comment: I'm still not seeing any dropdown show up, but you can see the `.active` icon working in my [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/q9mpasnt/4/).

Comment: Are you sure you can't see the dropdown? I see it just fine in your updated example. I would like to know in case that is a browser issue.

Comment: @ChartProblems It's working now. I have updated my [answer](http://jsfiddle.net/q9mpasnt/5/) with styles to change the color of the dropdown (and the highlighted letter in the dropdown).

Comment: What about editing the image that is located to the left of the dropdown when you replace the null's by an image path?